# How to change the focus state of a UITextView in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have created a custom textEditor and added a Binding boolean value that is being defined in other structs. I would like to focus on the textEditor, meaning that I can write to it with the keyboard up, when the boolean becomes true. Is it even possible with this code ?
Thanks in advance !

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ResizableTF: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var txt: String
    @Binding var height: CGFloat
    @Binding var lines: CGFloat
    @Binding var isFirstResponder: Bool
    
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 150
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return ResizableTF.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let view = UITextView()
        view.isEditable = true
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.isEditable = true
        view.isScrollEnabled = true
        view.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        view.textColor = .gray
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context){
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            if uiView.contentSize.height < maxHeight {
                self.height = uiView.contentSize.height
                if(uiView.contentSize.height == 38){
                    self.lines = 0
                }else{
                    self.lines = uiView.contentSize.height / 21 * 13 - 38
                }
            }
            uiView.text = self.txt
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate{
        
        var parent: ResizableTF
        let maxHeight: CGFloat = 150
        init(parent1: ResizableTF) {
            parent = parent1
        }
        
        func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            if self.parent.txt == "" {
                textView.text = ""
                textView.textColor = .black
            }
        }
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if textView.contentSize.height < self.maxHeight {
                    self.parent.height = textView.contentSize.height
                }
                self.parent.txt = textView.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add show/hide keyboard logic in updateUIView func as below

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    if isFirstResponder {
       uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
       uiView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    //rest of your code...
}
```